How to override Angular Inbuit function
I am working on an Angular 16 project and need to override a specific function within the built-in nonce.js file. However, I am unsure about the correct approach to achieve this. Could someone guide me on how to properly override a function in an internal Angular file? I have limited experience with modifying internal Angular files, and I am concerned about potential issues or best practices I should be aware of. Any detailed instructions or examples would be greatly appreciated, especially if they include steps to ensure that the changes are maintainable and do not cause conflicts during updates or with other parts of the application. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Altering dependencies is no recommended.
For the cases where this is the only alternative, you could change file in question and apply a patch-package.
